# What to do when a custom font appears as black boxes - FontForge

Tags: font-design, font-forge

I am trying to create a custom font that I can use in a book I am writing. I have drawn the glyphs I want in Photoshop, opened them individually in Illustrator and converted them to the .SVG format, and pasted them into Font Forge. All looks well to me.

To my horror, upon generating the font, it comes out as black boxes. I can see the faint outline of some of the glyphs in the boxes, like it started with a black background in the first place and stuck the black glyph over it or something, Thusly:

[image]

The W's and X's are visible because the font I was using did not have any special glyphs for those letters, so I left them as they were.

To the best of my knowledge, I've done everything correctly.

I've obviously made a mistake somewhere. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

*P.S. I am new to Font Forge. This is the first time I have used it, though I did look at several videos/articles on how to use it first.*

Comment: If this question is off topic (which I don't *think* it is), please let me know before down-voting.

Comment: FontForge has a graphical interface in which you can see the outlines and/or filled characters. Are the boxes visible in that? Then they were copied along with your 'character' data. You are concise on how you 'converted' Photoshop to SVG using Illustrator; I bet you clicked 'autotrace' and exported the entire path, without removing the white (!) background square (!!) that Autotrace creates by default.

Comment: Hmm... that could be. I am unfamiliar with Illustrator as well. How would I go about getting rid of the white background?

Comment: [Reading the Online Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/tracing-artwork-live-trace-or.html) might be a good start.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out how to remove the background and that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Note that even if your workflow may technically work, it sounds as if it will be less hassle to generate th eglyphs natively in FontForge.

Comment: It would be - except that I know how the tools in Photoshop work, and do not know how the tools in FF work.